# Merging two product star ratings with foreach in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, array-merge

There may be a better way to state the question, but I'm workin' with what I know.

On Woocommerce I'm trying to get the _wc_rating_count for each star (1-5), but also for two products; then I want to combine theme; e.g., I am merging the reviews of two products on one page, in one graph.

I am doing that this way:

```
$product_id = array( 2146, 2166 );
$ratings = array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1);

foreach ($product_id as $pid) :

    $product = wc_get_product($pid);

    foreach ($ratings as $rating) :

        $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count($rating);
        $percentage = ($rating_count / $count) * 100 . "%";

        //echo $rating_count . '<br/>';

    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

The problem is, I'm getting an array of 10 items (2 products x 5 star ratings( 5,4,3,2,1), and I need those values merged.

```
11
1
0
0
2
8
0
0
0
1
```

Where I need it to be

```
19
1
0
0
3
```

Do you know how I may get two arrays out of the embedded foreachs and merge them based on the $ratings array?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is in the `$count` variable? And what do you mean by `merged` values?

Comment: Hi Pete. Sorry, the $count is the total number of reviews (23), which I need broken up by star rating.

Merged values means the 11 and the 8 need to merge (both products' 5 stars), then the 1 and the 0, 0 and 0, 0 and 0, and 1 and 3.

Comment: So you need the sum of all `$rating_count` of one product per product? Or what do you like to achive? Or do you like to sum all `$rating_count` of all products but grouped by rating type (5,4,3,2,1)?

Comment: The $count is already the sum of both products combined.

I need to essentially merge each $rating (star rating) of the products together. In the above I was able to get the rating count per star per product, but that left me with two arrays into one.

I'd have to sum the 1st with the 6th, the 2nd with the 7th, etc, but that feels wrong.

Comment: Oh I see. You simply like to get the average rating of each product then? Like `2146` has a `3.16` rating  and `2166` a `4.37` rating? (example numbers) And do you like to sort them by that overall rating?

Comment: No, that's the wc_average_rating. I can get that per product. What I need is the "rating count, per star, per product." That gives me 10 values (2 products, 5 stars each); but I need them merged (2 products, 5 stars total, combined).

Comment: So you simply like to count all 5 stars rates, 4 stars rates, ... ?

Comment: Correct, so I need to get a sum of both of the 5 star rates, then a sum of both of the 4 star rates, etc.

In this I product all of the rates in a row, but they need to be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what do you like to achieve:

```
$product_ids = array( 2146, 2166 );
$ratings = array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
$rate_countings = array();

foreach ($product_ids as $pid){

    $product = wc_get_product($pid);

    foreach ($ratings as $rating){

        $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count($rating);
        //$percentage = ($rating_count / $count) * 100 . "%";

        if( !isset($rate_countings[$rating]) ){
            $rate_countings[$rating] = 0;
        }
        $rate_countings[$rating] += $rating_count;

    }

}

var_dump($rate_countings);
```